# Want to show car path between two station in google map using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary

I have HTML file and I have two zipcode one for source and second for destination. I want to show the car route between two station in HTML. can any body know how can i do this using google map.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want to stick with HTML, you need to figure out the encoded polyline of the route and then put it on the map. The easiest way to do this is to use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to get the overview polyline (not an exact line but it does what it's supposed to) and then put it on a [static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1).

If you're going to make it dynamic with javascript, make a asynchronous call to the Directions API, take the polyline and put it on a Google Map. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanrolds/ukRsp/) is an example of how to do it on Google Maps v3.

Here's that example boiled down a bit for the interesting parts:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.65905179951626, 7.3835928124999555);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: <PATH FROM DIRECTIONS API HERE>,
        levels: <RESULT FROM DECODE LEVELS>,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        map: map
    });
}

function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
    var decodedLevels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
        var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
        decodedLevels.push(level);
    }
    return decodedLevels;
}
```